# Visual Studio Code Как передавать параметры при отладке скрипта PHP CLI?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, консоль

Есть некий скрипт, который отрабатывает из командной строки:
php index.php --task=test
Я не нашёл как в Visual Studio Code передать скрипту параметры --task=test при режиме Launch Currently open script. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

В Visual Studio Code так и не получилось. 
Если что, в PHPStorm в Run/Debug Configuration нужно указать Name: index.php, File:/var/www/html/index.php и в Interpreter options: index.php --task=test и это работает.